# Android (Xamarin) padding in textview

Tags: android, xamarin, layout

I'm implementing an EULA with a checkbox, where part of the text is clickable. Through googling and from other answered questions here, I've used a checkbox with no text and a separate textview for the text, which in the C# code uses a SpannableString and ClickableSpan.

However, I'm having some problems with the layout of the checkbox and textview. Here is what the layout looks like now:
[I want to get the one on top to look like the one below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjUCc.png)

As can be seen, there's a large unknown padding on the left and right of the textview even though the padding is explicitly set to 0. Here is the xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/registerMobileField"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/pdpaChkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0"
        android:text=""
        android:scaleX="0.80"
        android:scaleY="0.80" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pdpaText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/pdpaChkbox"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="0"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
        android:text="@string/pdpa"
        android:scaleX="0.80"
        android:scaleY="0.80" />
</RelativeLayout>
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pdpaChkbox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/registerMobileField"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
    android:text="@string/pdpa"
    android:scaleX="0.80"
    android:scaleY="0.80" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not unknown padding this is `scaleX` and `scaleY` property you have given to you that you have given `CheckBox` and `TextView`. just remove these properties from your `CheckBox` and `TextView` and give it to the `RelativeLayout` then your both case will same as follows.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/registerMobileField"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:scaleX="0.80"
        android:scaleY="0.80"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/pdpaChkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pdpaText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/pdpaChkbox"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/pdpaChkbox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
        android:layout_below="@id/registerMobileField"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleX="0.80"
        android:scaleY="0.80" />
```

I hope its work for you

Comment: Thank you! It works. I didn't realise that the scale factor doesn't change the container of the scaled element.